# Way to override taskbar icon of already running arbitrary program instance?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

I have open several instances of programs like cygwin terminal, putty, etc., for different but related things.

It would help me work if they had different icons each, because I have open a relatively big number of applications for work.

I've ducked several queries but no luck yet.

Is it possible to override the taskbar icon of an already running application, per pid (per instance) or per window, via some tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the 7 Taskbar Tweaker:

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v3-4

It has a setting to do just that:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but (as zakius pointed out in a non-answer), I don't see any setting to change the taskbar icon.